# How can you have a xEmacs-like-Auctex in MacVim?

Tags: macos, vim, emacs, auctex

I would like to have a figures right in my MacVim, similarly as in xEmacs' AucTex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim is pure-text, and so it wouldn't be able to replicate [preview-latex](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/):

> AUCTeX includes preview-latex which makes LaTeX a tightly integrated component of your editing workflow by visualizing selected source chunks (such as single formulas or graphics) directly as images in the source buffer.

So if that's a feature you need integrated into the editor (rather than calling out from the editor for a quick external preview, which would be possible) than you're out of luck.

As for the [rest of the feature list](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/features.html), much of it looks vim-able.  You may have some luck with [VIM-LaTex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) or [auctex.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=162)